# Fees from portals like coinbase or bitestamp to Bank/Credit Card

Tags: transaction-fees

there is something not really clear to me in the buy/sell process.

When I sell bitcoin on sites like coinbase I am requested to pay a 1% fee. What about the fees to transfer the money back to my bank account (or Credit Card)? Are they included in the 1%?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinbase has a separate bank fee (currently $0.15) in addition to their transaction fee.

Comment: 0.15$ is nothing...how can they cover costs?

Comment: I guess it depends on how much it costs them to use the ACH for deposits/debits.  I'm not a banker, so I can't help you with that.